# character encoding error UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1

Tags: php, html, laravel, character-encoding

I just created a project without a database in Laravel and I use ISO 8859-1 decoding in HTML. The problem is that it is only considering UTF-8. I've used header in PHP and it didn't work. Content-Type continues UTF-8

[image]

The beginning of my HTML looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO 8859-1');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO 8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

But, the lyrics come out this way:

[image]

Comment: When you start a new project why do you change it to ISO? You should really use UTF-8.

Comment: Why? I was told that ISO is more modern.

Comment: UTF-8 is the actual standard so why do you think that ISO is more modern? UTF-8 has a wider range of symbols and that the reason why the framework and PHP work with them. So when you change it you fight the framework... and you get a lot of trouble.

Comment: I'm from Brazil, I don't know if that matters. But in relation to accents, they say that the ISO is more acceptable here. But maybe you're right.